# What is the '>8' for in the git commit file?

Tags: git

In git commit files, there is a line that looks like this:

```
#                           
# ------------------------ >8 ------------------------
# Do not modify or remove the line above.
# Everything below it will be ignored.
```

It wasn't until today that I noticed the `>8` in the middle of the line break. Why was that chosen? As opposed to just continuing the dashes?

Comment: Looks like ASCII art for scissors to me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+8+dash

Comment: Just ✄ in a mirror.